# Python for loop iterating an already iterated item

Tags: python, for-loop

So I was trying to solve this leetcode problem:

**Input: command = "G()(al)"**

**Output: "Goal"**

**Explanation: The Goal Parser interprets the command as follows:**

**G -> G**

**() -> o**

**(al) -> al**

**The final concatenated result is "Goal".**

This is my code:

```
def interpret(command: str) -> str:
        
        res = ''
        
        for i in command:
            
            if i == 'G':
                res += i
            
            if i == '(':
                ind = command.index(i)
                if command[ind + 1] == ')':
                    res += 'o'
                if command[ind + 1] == 'a':
                    res += 'al'
        
        return res
```

The problem is, instead of returning 'Goal', the function returns 'Goo'. So I changed the function to the following to see what's going on:

```
for i in command:
            if i == '(':
                print(command.index(i))
```

And the above code prints out this

```
1
1
```

which means the loop is iterating an element twice?

What did I do wrong and how can I fix the function to return the correct output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`command.index()` gives you the first occurrence of '('.

Rewrite your function as follows:

```
def interpret(command: str) -> str:

    res = ""

    for c, i in enumerate(command):

        if i == "G":
            res += i

        if i == "(":
            ind = c
            if command[ind + 1] == ")":
                res += "o"
            if command[ind + 1] == "a":
                res += "al"

    return res
```

Comment: Note: It's *really* weird to name the index `c` and the value `i`; `i` is almost always the name of the index. I realize the OP used `i` for the value, but ugh, don't encourage that.

Comment: Ohhh now that makes perfect sense! Thanks mate